# Config httpd-vhosts.conf to access like http://IP/v-host

Tags: apache, xampp, vhosts

i need help with correct configuring my httpd-vhosts.conf. I'm using xampp and it's default vhost configs:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@myhost
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/myhost"
    ServerName myhost
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
    ErrorLog "logs/myhost.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/myhost.localhost-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to config it so, that it will use this mask - IP/host, for example:

```
    http://199.99.99.9/my-host1
    http://199.99.99.9/my-host2
    #199.99.99.9 is my IP
```

Any help guys will be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [guide](http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/) to add vhost to xampp

> For example, say you had another Web site for ClientB. You’d add 127.0.0.1 clientB.local in the hosts file and the C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf would look like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *80
  <VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
  </VirtualHost>
  <VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Documents and Settings\Me\My Documents\clientA\website"
    ServerName clientA.local
  <Directory "C:\Documents and Settings\Me\My Documents\clientA\website">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Documents and Settings\Me\My Documents\clientB\website"
    ServerName clientB.local
  <Directory "C:\Documents and Settings\Me\My Documents\clientB\website">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And **restart** httpd

Comment: i also have same kind of issue can you help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949200/page-not-found-on-request-url-in-zend-2-framework-application